# Android Recycler and ButterKnitfe error in Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, butterknife

1. ButterKnife.bind(this) error

> ```
> private void bindButterKnife() {
>
>         ButterKnife.bind(this);
>     }
> ```

2. (this, new ArrayList()) and (new LinearLayoutManager(this)); error

> ```
> private void setUserRecyclerView() {
>     mUsersChatAdapter = new UsersChatAdapter(this, new ArrayList<User>());
>     mUsersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
>     mUsersRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
>     mUsersRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUsersChatAdapter);
> }
> ```

someone help me pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. override `onViewCreated` and use ButterKnife as `ButterKnife.bind(this, view)`
2. Use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

   ```
   @Override
   public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
         ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
   }
   ```

Comment: (this, new ArrayList()) and (new LinearLayoutManager(this)); can you help me

Comment: @ThLez use `getActivity()` instead of `this` if the argument is a `Context` object